# Scala Map And Pair Manipulation

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am a beginner in Scala.
 I read this code about Map manipulation but can't understand how it works.

```
val terms = Map (1 -> 1.0, 2-> 2.0)
val (exp, coeff) = (2, 4.0)
exp -> (coeff + terms(exp))  //> res: (Int, Double) = (2,6.0)
coeff + terms(exp)  //> res: Double = 6.0
```

I think the third line probably applied a map function,
but the right hand side is apparently a number.
Why the output is a pair?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val (exp, coeff) = (2, 4.0)
```

This is a deconstructor, it assigns the values `2` and `4.0` to the names `exp` and `coeff`. `exp` is now `2` and `coeff` is now `4.0`.

```
terms(exp)
```

This is a map-lookup which results in 2.0

```
exp -> (coeff + terms(exp))
```

This arrow `->` is a short hand term for constructing a Pair. It now has the values `2` and `6.0` because `coeff + terms(exp)` is `6.0`.

Comment: oh I get it.
     `1 -> 0.2` 
would create
`(Int, Double) = (1, 0.2)`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`terms(exp)` accesses the value of the "map object" `terms` at the key defined by `exp`.

In contrast to this, the usage of a "map method" would look like this:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val double = (i: Int) => i * 2
val list2 = list.map(double)
printf(list2.toString)
```

`list.map(double)` executes the function literal `double` for every member of the list and gives back a new List object.

The printed output is:

```
List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

`terms(exp)` is a map lookup, resolving to `2.0`

`(coeff + terms(exp))` is, therefore `4.0 + 2.0`

In `exp -> (coeff + terms(exp))` the arrow `->` constructs a pair of the left and right operands.